# How to uncheck a box on IE using VBA and editing HTML

Tags: html, vba, explorer

I would like to "uncheck" a box on IE using VBA. I've tried to use "element.checked = false", but, on that case, doesn't work. So, visualizing the html document, I've seen that uncheck box doesn't have the attribute "checked = "checked"", so, How can I edit the HTML to uncheck this box using VBA?

Here's a code:

```
<input name="Seg" id="form_Seg" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
Seg
<input name="Ter" id="form_Ter" type="checkbox">
Ter
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I would like a code, in VBA that removes checked="checked" at the code of html to uncheck it

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?  You've just shown the html so far.  We cant see the web page to test our approaches etc.  I would do something like so `Dim o As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set o = ie.document.getElementById("form_seg")
o.Checked = True`